# C Implementation of linkedlist

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I am trying to print the values stored in a linked list but i'm running into a infinite loop.Please could some one tell me what is wrong with my code. I am able to successfully collect the data of the nodes but when printing the list i run into a continuous loop. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int data; //4 bytes
    struct node *next; // 4bytes 32 bit and 8 bytes i 64bit cp
};

int main(){
    struct node *head,*newnode,*temp;
    head = NULL ;
    temp = head;
    int count=0, choice=1;

    while(choice){
        newnode = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        printf("Enter data:");
        scanf("%d",&newnode-> data);
        newnode->next = head;

        if(head == 0){
            head = temp = newnode;
        }
        else{
            temp->next = newnode;
            temp = newnode;

        }
        printf(" %d ",temp->data);

        printf("Do you want to continue? 0/1");
        scanf("%d",&choice);
    }
    int i = 0;
    temp = head;
    while( temp!=NULL){
        printf("%d ",temp->data);
        temp=temp->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Oka - thank you for fixing the formatting/indentation.  im3dbabasia - Q: have you stepped through the code in the debugger?  Q: Are you *familiar* with how to use your debugger?  "Debugging" is absolutely your "first step".  Hint: Why are you setting `newnode->next = head;`  each time you add a new node?

Comment: If you add nodes to the tail end, you should *never* point `newnode->next` to `head`. Instead, `newnode->next` should just be assigned `NULL`.

Comment: Consider renaming `temp` to `tail` or change the linked list to insert nodes from the `head` end.

Comment: @paulsm4 i have changed newnode->next to be NULL. Hope thats ok

Comment: As an exercise, add nodes to the `head` end of the linked list. That's a quite common thing to do with linked lists. If you have been looking at other implementations that can explain the confusion. It will "reverse" the linked list though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt it's within the scope of the homework problem in question, but it's really helpful to break linked list tasks down into smaller problems.

We start with this node definition:

```c
struct node {
    int data; //4 bytes
    struct node *next; // 4bytes 32 bit and 8 bytes i 64bit cp
};
```

Which I'm going to typedef to make my life slightly easier.

```c
typedef struct node {
    int data; //4 bytes
    struct node *next; // 4bytes 32 bit and 8 bytes i 64bit cp
} node_t;
```

Let's find the last node for a given head. We'll create a `node_t` pointer called `current` and use it to walk the list until it's at the last node. We'll know it's the last because its `next` member will be `NULL`. Of course, if `head` is `NULL`, then we'll just return `NULL` immediately.

```c
node_t *last_node(node_t *head) {
    if (head == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    node_t *current;

    for (current = head; current->next != NULL; current = current->next);

    return current;
}
```

Now, let's add a value to a list with a given head. We can provide a shortcut by returning a pointer the new last node. We'll also short-circuit a lot of work if `head` is `NULL`.

Otherwise we'll get the last node using the `last_node` function we defined, set its `next` to the new node, and return a pointer to the new node.

```c
node_t *add_to_list(node_t *head, int value) {
    node_t * new_node = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    new_node->data = value;
    new_node->next = NULL;

    if (head == NULL) {
        return new_node;
    }

    node_t *last = last_node(head);
    last->next = new_node;
    return new_node;
}
```

And finally we can write a function to print the list. Given that you've already seen walking the list, this should look pretty familiar.

```c
void print_list(node_t *head) {
    for (node_t *current = head; 
         current->next != NULL; 
         current = current->next) {
        printf("%d ", current->data);
    }
}
```

Breaking down big problems into smaller problems is crucial. Practice it!

Comment: Dynamically finding the last node of a linked list is rarely wise. I would not accept a commit like this in a code review. If you need to append to the list on a regular, you either create a doubly linked list or you keep a reference to the last node.

Comment: Of course. But it provides a handy way to demonstrate iterating over the list.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new node, you set it's "next" node to the head node. That's how the loop is made.
Set it to NULL.

And afterwards you set the new node as the "current node's next node" and the "current node" as well.
I believe you wanted to set it to temp's next node and then move the temp onto it's next node.

Also please don't compare head with 0... If you expect it to be NULL compare to NULL.

Comment: I agree on the last remark. You would either use `if(head == NULL){` or `if(!head){`.

Comment: Thank you very much your remarks helped!